# grep -f file.csv input.csv I tee output.csv shows no data in file

Tags: grep

```
   grep -f file.txt input.csv I tee output.csv
```

This hangs as if it is processessing; however, after a few minutes, it stops. It creates an empty output file.

file.txt is a file with email addresses listed  with \n delimiter such as:

```
   Johndoe@yahoo.com
   Janedoe@hotmail.com
   Manny@gmail.com
```

This file has about 30,000 lines.

input.csv is a comma delimited file such as:

```
   John,doe,johndoe@yahoo.com,address,dob,etc
```

...and has about 50,000 lines.

output.csv should only have rows that contain the email addresses listed in file.txt, preserving the contents of each row.

Please help me!

Comment: i don't think you can use grep for this type of thing, you might want to look at writing a script in python or perl

Comment: In your example output.csv is empty because there is **no** string or substring from file.txt in input.csv.